Disarming Paradox PCS265 LTE via SMS
Before buying this module, I'm researching following questions:

Is there a limit of users who disarm the Paradox system by sending SMS to PCS265 LTE module?
Is there possibility to limit arm\disarm users by their cellphone numbers? In case if the user password will be stolen, the person sending SMS from another phone number is unable to disarm the system, because his cell phone number "is not listed" in PCS265 module.

Unfortunately, the official documentation does not explain this clearly. It only tells that there are 16 users who may receive SMS reports, but no info regarding the arm\disarm feature.
Does anybody know? Would be glad for any thoughts.
Thanks!
Alex

I would suggest that you contact the company selling this.

Yes, after receiving their answer, posted it here too as an answer. Maybe someone else will have the same question.

Found out that it is possible to disarm the system from any phone number. The user who disarms it, have to know his personal pass code and have to follow the defined in the documentation message format.
Unfortunately, there is no limit of cell phone numbers from which the system could be disarmed.
